# PDEs with more than 3 boundary condition

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

We consider $w(x,t)$ be the solution of 1D Schrodinger equation $iw_t-w_{xx} = 0$ with the boundary condition is given as $w(0,t)=w(1,t)=w_x(0,t)=0$. How can I prove that $w =0$?

Comment: Separation of variables.

Comment: We can not do it

Comment: This actually seems more like your problem is ill posed, but anyway. Setting $w(x,t) = X(x) T(t)$, you get two ODEs 

\begin{align}
T' &= i \lambda T \\
X'' &= - \lambda X
\end{align} 

where $- \lambda$ is your separation constant, with conditions $X(0) = X(1) = X'(0) = 0$. Solve the ODE for $X$ when $\lambda < 0, \lambda = 0, \lambda > 0$ and see what the eigenfunction in $X$ is. Then, as $w(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$ and $X = \dots$